# "That username is already taken." but there is no entry in DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

In my environment I'm trying to create a new superuser via `python .\manage.py createsuperuser`.

However, when I enter the name I get the following error: `Error: That username is already taken.`.

So I check the `auth_user` table in PgAdmin and I can see there are no entries.

Moreover, the `QuerySet` is empty when I do the following:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
superusers = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
superusers
>>> <QuerySet []>
```

I'm using a managed cloud-hosted PostgreSQL server with the `postgresql_psycopg2` client, and have checked that all credentials are correct.

What am I doing incorrectly? I'm using Django `4.1.2`.

Comment: What you can see with User.objects.all()?

Comment: My guess is the `username` that already exists, not the property `is_superuser`. Like @NixonSparrow said, show all the users and more than likely you will see the `username` already in existence.

Comment: `User.objects.all()` also returns `<QuerySet []>`